# Reputation indicator green color is different in stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com

The reputation indicator green color is different in the stackexchange.com header.

For example in the meta.stackexchange.com header the reputation indicator color is `color: #5eba7d`

> [image: META SE]

But in the stackexchange.com header the reputation indicator color is `color: #45A163`

> [image: SE]

Can this color code be consistent in all the Stack Exchange site's headers?

Comment: It looks like the color on sites uses a theme color, while the one on stackexchange.com uses the old hardcoded color.